# How to get invoices from ZohoBook with a custom field as parameter, which contain array of IDs

Tags: invoice, zoho, accounting, zoho-deluge, zohobooks

We included a custom field called "property_Id" while creating an invoice. In order to retrieve a list of invoices, we currently use the custom field by passing property_id='12345' as a parameter. However, we now wish to pass an array of property ids instead of a single id. What steps should we take to achieve this?

```
`
static async list(accessToken: string) {

        const params: any = {
            organization_id: ZohoConfig.organizationId,
            page: query?.page,
            per_page: query?.per_page,

        // working with now
        cf_property_d:"12345"
            // WANT this
            // I would like to retrieve the data that is included in an invoice containing any of the IDs listed here.
        cf_property_d:["12345","12346","123888","999999","1111222"]

        };

        const url = `https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices?`;

        const config = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            params,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Zoho-oauthtoken 123456789`
            },
        };
        axios(config)
    .then(response => {
    
            console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
    });
    }


`
```